# JSON collection of objects isn't binding correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, serialization

I have a website where I am uploading an Excel document to the server through AJAX (Telerik control). When the document is uploaded it will return a JSON object collection of currency exchange rates. I then save that collection using the jQuery $.data() method. Then I call the grid to bind and pass my JSON object to my controller to bind the data to the grid. Everything seems to be working up to the point where the Action on the controller binds to the collection.

What am I missing, notice how the *response from SelectImportedCurrencyRates* returns '1/1/1' for dates, country code is 'null' and the exchange rate is '0'. When I Debug and check the bound object `ICollection<CurrencyExchangeRate> currencyRatesImported`, its bound with those values as '0', '1/1/1' and null

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadRates(HttpPostedFileBase importRateDocument)
    {
        var rates = CurrencyExchangeRateRepository.ReadExcelRates(importRateDocument.InputStream, importRateDocument.FileName);
        return Json(rates);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult SelectImportedCurrencyRates([Bind(Prefix = "CurrencyRatesImported")] ICollection<CurrencyExchangeRate> currencyRatesImported)
    {
        return View(currencyRatesImported != null ? 
            new GridModel(currencyRatesImported) : 
           new GridModel(new List<CurrencyExchangeRate>()));
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onUploadRatesSuccess(e) {
    $('body').data('CurrencyRatesImported', e.response);

    var grid = $('#CurrencyExchangeRates').data('tGrid');
    grid.ajaxRequest();
}

function onCurrencyRatesImportedDataBinding(args) {
    var currencyRatesImported = $('body').data('CurrencyRatesImported');
    console.log(currencyRatesImported);
    args.data = $.extend(args.data, { CurrencyRatesImported: currencyRatesImported });

    args.data = args.data;
}
```

**e.Response passed to onUploadRatesSuccess (result from ActionResult UploadRates()**

```
[{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1325656800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0145},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1325743200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0212},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1325829600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0241},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1326088800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0265},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1326175200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0187},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1326261600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0209},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1326348000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0207},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1326434400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0245},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1326693600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0182},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1326780000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0143},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1326866400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0139},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1326952800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0091},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1327039200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.014},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1327298400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0066},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1327384800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0108},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1327471200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0121},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1327557600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9997},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1327644000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0015},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1327903200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0046},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1328162400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9978},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1328248800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9986},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1328508000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9957},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1328594400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9949},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1328680800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9953},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1328767200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.994},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1328853600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9956},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1329112800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9998},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1329199200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0007},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1329285600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9976},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1329372000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0003},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1329458400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9969},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1329717600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9924},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1329804000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9957},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1329890400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9996},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1329976800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9973},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1330063200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9987},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1330322400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0002},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1330408800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9958},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1330581600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9958},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1330668000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9878},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1330927200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9937},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1331013600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0017},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1331100000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0023},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1331186400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9934},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1331272800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9889},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1331528400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9935},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1331614800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9906},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1331701200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9915},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1331787600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9929},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1331874000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9913},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1332133200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.988},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1332219600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9934},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1332306000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9931},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1332392400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0003},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1332478800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9984},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1332738000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9915},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1332824400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9925},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1332910800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9965},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1332997200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9992},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1333429200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9896},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1333515600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9971},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1333602000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.99385},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1333688400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.99565},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1333947600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.99761},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1334034000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0027},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1334120400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.002},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1334206800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9966},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1334293200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9975},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1334552400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0016},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1334638800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9876},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1334725200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9958},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1334811600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.99},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1334898000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9909},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1335157200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.995},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1335243600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9885},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1335330000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9853},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1335416400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9841},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1335502800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.981},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1335848400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.981},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1335934800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9891},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1336021200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9867},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1336107600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9863},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1336366800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.99636},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1336453200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.996},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1336539600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0044},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1336626000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0022},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1336712400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9968},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1336971600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0024},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1337058000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0038},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1337144400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0088},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1337230800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0163},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1337317200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0179},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1337576400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0218},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1337662800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0172},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1337749200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0283},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1337835600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0262},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1337922000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0289},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1338181200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0253},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1338267600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0222},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1338354000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0297},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1338526800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0297},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1338786000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.04141},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1338872400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.04154},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1338958800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0333},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1339045200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0242},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1339131600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0314},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1339390800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0289},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1339477200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0293},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1339563600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.025},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1339650000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0252},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1339736400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0236},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1339995600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0254},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1340082000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.018},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1340168400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0202},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1340254800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0231},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1340341200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0272},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1340600400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0304},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1340773200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0283},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1340859600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0339},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1341205200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0261},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1341291600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0132},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1341378000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0126},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1341464400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0139},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1341550800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0188},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1341810000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0199},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1341896400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0209},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1341982800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0206},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1342069200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0248},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1342155600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.014},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1342414800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0159},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1342501200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0166},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1342587600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0109},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1342674000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0073},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1342760400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0102},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1343019600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0176},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1343106000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0198},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1343192400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0195},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1343278800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0097},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1343365200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0058},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1343624400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0027},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1343797200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0027},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1343883600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0041},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1343970000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9997},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1344229200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9995},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1344315600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9967},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1344402000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.995},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1344488400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9917},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1344574800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.991},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1344834000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9932},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1344920400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9919},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1345006800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9897},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1345093200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9883},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1345179600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9882},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1345438800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9894},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1345525200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9855},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1345611600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.993},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1345698000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9916},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1345784400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.99121},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1346043600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.99234},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1346130000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9855},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1346216400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9885},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1346302800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9923},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1346648400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9923},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1346734800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9865},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1346821200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9917},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1346907600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9819},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1346994000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9771},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1347253200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9757},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1347339600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9727},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1347426000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9751},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1347512400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9751},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1347598800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9687},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1347858000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9719},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1347944400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9743},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1348030800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9761},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1348117200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9777},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1348203600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9763},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1348462800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9795},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1348549200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9769},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1348635600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9855},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1348722000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.984},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1349067600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1349154000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9832},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1349240400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.988},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1349326800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9816},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1349413200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9756},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1349672400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9761},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1349758800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9783},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1349845200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9787},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1349931600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.977},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1350018000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9801},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1350277200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9805},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1350363600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9861},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1350450000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9818},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1350536400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9823},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1350622800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.991},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1350882000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9933},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1350968400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9926},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1351054800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9916},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1351141200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9938},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1351227600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9976},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1351486800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0004},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1351573200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9993},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1351746000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9993},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1351832400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.99925},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1352095200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9966},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1352181600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9948},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1352268000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9959},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1352354400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9979},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1352440800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0017},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1352700000000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0004},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1352786400000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0013},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1352872800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0032},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1352959200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0027},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1353045600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0034},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1353304800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9956},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1353391200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9979},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1353477600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9977},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1353564000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9981},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1353650400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9928},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1353909600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9951},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1353996000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9943},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1354082400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9936},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1354168800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9917},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1354514400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9917},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1354600800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9927},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1354687200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9929},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1354773600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9895},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1354860000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9887},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1355119200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9872},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1355205600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9868},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1355292000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9852},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1355378400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9841},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1355464800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9866},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1355724000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9844},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1355810400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9846},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1355896800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9869},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1355983200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9887},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1356069600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9947},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1356328800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.99358},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1356415200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.99304},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1356501600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.99125},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1356588000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9936},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1356674400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9956},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1357106400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9837},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1357192800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9851},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1357279200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9857},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1357538400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9859},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1357624800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9871},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1357711200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9874},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1357797600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9866},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1357884000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9837},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1358143200000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9857},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1358229600000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9837},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1358316000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9858},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1358402400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9854},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1358488800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9938},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1358748000000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9939},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1358834400000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9935},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1358920800000)\/","ExchangeRate":0.9986},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1359007200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0032},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1359093600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0087},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1359352800000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0092},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1359439200000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0042},{"CountryCode":"CAD","Date":"\/Date(1359525600000)\/","ExchangeRate":1.0029}]
```

**Binding call to SelectImportedCurrencyRates**
[image: Binding call to SelectImportedCurrencyRates']

**Response from SelectImportedCurrencyRates**
[image]

**CurrencyExchangeRate class**

```
[Serializable()]
public class CurrencyExchangeRate
{

    public string CountryCode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public System.DateTime Date
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double ExchangeRate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the serialization of the collection I was sending up. It was passing an array up, instead of a serialized JSON object.

Here is what the serialization method should look like.

```
function serialize(prefix, data) {
    var result = {},
        dateRegex = /^\/Date\((.*?)\)\/$/;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var field in data[i]) {
            var value = data[i][field];
            if (typeof value === "string") {
                var date = dateRegex.exec(value);
                if (date) {
                    value = $.telerik.formatString("{0:d}", new Date(parseInt(date[1])));
                }
            }
            result[prefix + "[" + i + "]." + field] = value;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

So then when I call **onCurrencyRatesImportedDataBinding** it will serialize my object of currency exchange rates and pass them up properly.

```
function onCurrencyRatesImportedDataBinding(args) {
    var currencyRatesImported = $('body').data('CurrencyRatesImported');
    console.log(currencyRatesImported);
    args.data = $.extend(args.data, serialize("currencyExchangeRates", currencyRatesImported));

    args.data = args.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the format of the dates being sent across the wire.

Unfortunately the `DefaultModelBinder` in MVC doesn't know how to bind these dates.

You'll need to extend the `DefaultModelBinder`.  See e.g.

- http://taintedsanctity.tumblr.com/post/6425063095/asp-mvc-model-binding-json-dates-serialized-in
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7849322/206297

Comment: Thanks I will probably experience that issue next so that will come in handy. I already tried going down the path of just using the `CountryCode` property (removing the date and the `ExchangeRate` double) to see if it would work with just the one string property and it still lost the `CountryCode` in translation (binding). The weird part is that it picks up that there are 265 objects, just cant translate it.

Comment: Bit of a stab in the dark but what does your `CurrencyExchangeRate` class look like?  Does it have a default constructor?  Its properties are public?  Think MVC would error if not but worth checking.

Comment: I included the class up above, it uses the default constructor, nothing special. All its properties are public. It's a simple POCO class.